# Collectors groupingBy based on City

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

I have a person object which has a name and a list of addresses as parameters. The address has a street, type, city, and personId 
I want to get a grouping map by the city. I am stuck

This is my code so far :

```
Map<String,List<Person>> MAP = personRepository.findAll().stream() 
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(person->person.getAddresses().stream()
         .map(address -> address.getCity())
         ."some kind of collector I assume"))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using `flatMap` possibly as :

```
Map<String, List<Person>> finalPersonMap = personRepository.findAll().stream()
            .flatMap(person -> person.getAddresses().stream()
                    .map(address -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(address.getCity(), person)))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Assuming the basic models to be like:

```
static class Person {
    List<Address> addresses;

    List<Address> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }
}

static class Address {
    String city;

    String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
}
```